# How to get the focused/selected object in delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I have a PageControl object with several pages in separate tabs.
Each tab contains a lot of objects such as `TEdits` and `TComboBoxes`.
Lets say I'm in "Tab A" entering text in a `TEdit` and then the software change tab to "Tab B" and then back to "Tab A". Then the `TEdit` is no longer selected so I need to select it again to continue writing.

Now to my question:
How can I save/get/store the selected object before change of tab so that I can return to the same object when back to the previous tab?

Thanks!

---

2018-02-15
Update:

Thanks @ExDev!

`Screen.ActiveControl` was what I where looking for! I solved it like this:

```
var 
  FocusObject : TWinControl;
begin
  // Save selected object  
  FocusObject:= Screen.ActiveControl;

  // Restore selected object  
  FocusObject.SetFocus;
end;
```

Comment: Just an idea, but if the `tab`has a `Tag`property you could store the focused component in there. Then you could retrieve it and set it back focused.

Comment: @Sonocronic: If my [answer solved the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/386306)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [TPageControl.OnChanging](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TPageControl_OnChanging.html) event to store the focused control before changing the active tab and the [TPageControl.OnChange](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/ComCtrls_TPageControl_OnChange.html) event to restore its focused state.

**Example:**

```
TForm1 = class(TForm)
    PageControl1: TPageControl;
    TabSheet1: TTabSheet;
    TabSheet2: TTabSheet;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Edit2: TEdit;
    Edit3: TEdit;
    Edit4: TEdit;
    procedure PageControl1Changing(Sender: TObject; var AllowChange: Boolean);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure PageControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
  private
    FActiveControls : array of TWinControl;
  end;

...

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  SetLength(FActiveControls, PageControl1.PageCount);
end;

procedure TForm1.PageControl1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if(FActiveControls[TPageControl(Sender).ActivePageIndex] <> nil)
  then FActiveControls[TPageControl(Sender).ActivePageIndex].SetFocus();
end;

procedure TForm1.PageControl1Changing(Sender: TObject;
  var AllowChange: Boolean);
begin
  FActiveControls[TPageControl(Sender).ActivePageIndex] := Screen.ActiveControl;
end;
```

**Note:**

Both events are not called if you change the active page in code, for example, by setting the value of `TPageControl.ActivePage`.